# ModuleNotFoundError while compiling ROS 2 beginner package

Tags: ros2, cmake, ament, message-generation, build-package

I'm attempting to build a ROS 2 package named `my_robot_interfaces` using the colcon build tool. However, I'm encountering the error message `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'` when trying to generate ROS 2 interfaces for the package's message type.

Below is the CmakeList.txt file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.8)
project(my_robot_interfaces)

if(NOT CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD)
  set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
endif()

if(CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "Clang")
  add_compile_options(-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)
endif()

set(numpy_DIR /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/numpy/core/include)

find_package(ament_cmake REQUIRED)
find_package(rosidl_default_generators REQUIRED)

rosidl_generate_interfaces(${PROJECT_NAME}
  "msg/HardwareStatus.msg"
)

ament_export_dependencies(rosidl_default_runtime)
ament_package()
```

Below is the package.xml file

```
 <msg>
 <name>HardwareStatus</name>
 <version>0.0.0</version>
 <datatype>builtin_interfaces/msg/Time</datatype>
 <fields>
   <field type="int64" name="temperature">
    <description>Current temperature of the robot</description>
   </field>
   <field type="bool" name="are_motor_ready">
    <description>Whether the robot's motors are ready for operation</description>
   </field>
   <field type="string" name="debug_message">
    <description>Debugging message</description>
   </field>
 </fields>
</msg>
```

Below is the error message

```
Starting >>> my_robot_interfaces
--- stderr: my_robot_interfaces                         
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
CMake Error at /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_generator_py/cmake/rosidl_generator_py_generate_interfaces.cmake:204 (message):
  execute_process(/usr/local/bin/python3.6 -c 'import
  numpy;print(numpy.get_include())') returned error code 1
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/humble/share/ament_cmake_core/cmake/core/ament_execute_extensions.cmake:48 (include)
  /opt/ros/humble/share/rosidl_cmake/cmake/rosidl_generate_interfaces.cmake:286 (ament_execute_extensions)
  CMakeLists.txt:25 (rosidl_generate_interfaces)


---
Failed   <<< my_robot_interfaces [2.34s, exited with code 1]

Summary: 0 packages finished [4.28s]
  1 package failed: my_robot_interfaces
  1 package had stderr output: my_robot_interfaces
```

I am trying to learn ROS 2 basics from Udemy. If someone could help me, it will be very helpfull.

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! 

① Please install `python3-numpy` package using `sudo apt install python3-numpy` ② Make sure the following command works `python3.6 -c 'import numpy;print(numpy.__version__)'` and shows `1.xx.x`